# Confused in writing paths in php

Tags: php, path, include

I am confused writing a path in include.

Here are some details

I have a file index.php which is here :

localhost/widget/explore/staff/index.php

and want to include a file named constants.php which is here :

localhost/widget/includes/constants.php

Tell me how to write the required path

```
include '?';
```

Comment: you trying to use `include()` core function of PHP or you talking about `include_path` PHP configuration option?

Comment: @webbandit Technically, `include` is a preprocessor directive, not a function, which is why I prefer it without parentheses, the way OP writes it :-]

Comment: Warning: require_once(connection.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Yousuf\Desktop\Web\localhost\widget_corp\explore\staff\index.php on line 6

Comment: Still getting error grrr

Comment: Now its working thinks everyone especially lynks for your help

Answer (score 3):

```
include("..\\..\\includes\\constants.php");
```

Or try this;

```
include("C:\\Users\\Yousuf\\Desktop\\Web\\localhost\\widget_corp\\includes\\constants.php");
```

Comment: `include('/widget/includes/constants.php');` - I don't think `/widget/` folder is in root ))

Comment: not working still getting this error : Warning: require_once(connection.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Yousuf\Desktop\Web\localhost\widget_corp\explore\staff\index.php on line 6

Comment: Written like this, php uses the apache document root, not the hdd root. (you can't do an **include('/etc/passwd');** you have to do an **include('../../../../../etc/passwd');** for example.) Edit: this is assuming apache and php have a typical secure configuration.

Comment: From PHP dosc site: `If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.`.

Comment: Your executable file is in `C:\Users\Yousuf\Desktop\Web\localhost\widget_corp\explore\staff\index.php`. Where are files you want to include? Give us FULL (absolute) path!

Comment: @webbandit yep, looks like you're correct. weird, I could have sworn I've done this without problems in the past.

Comment: @yusufiqbalpk *I just wan't you to write a path for me* A little politeness would go a long way, when requesting help from others.

Comment: @webbandit C:\Users\Yousuf\Desktop\Web\localhost\widget_corp\includes\constants.php (absolute path of the file i want to include in my index.php) whose absolute path is : C:\Users\Yousuf\Desktop\Web\localhost\widget_corp\explore\staff\index.php

Comment: @yusufiqbalpk - what paths have you actually tried so far? We're all working blind here as we could be suggesting things that you already have. Don't forget that as you're using Windows (of some flavour), you will need to change all the '/' to '\' in the answers given so far. Also, show us what the `include_path` value is from your php.ini file.

Comment: @DaveyBoy
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path

Comment: @yusufiqbalpk i have edited the answer, if the absolute path given there does not work, there's something you're not telling us :P

Comment: in `index.php` use `include('..\..\..\includes\constants.php')`

Comment: put the constants file into `c:\php\includes` and just use `include ('constants.php');`. OR create a subfolder in `c:\php\includes` (e.g., `c:\php\includes\myfiles`), put the file in there and use `include ('myfiles\constants.php');`

Comment: The previous answer worked. There was a typo. Sorry for that Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to remember is to make sure that any files which contain sensitive information (DB login/passwords etc) are stored **outside** of the app's document path. You don't want to let someone download this type of file from a web browser pretty easily.

Taking the above into consideration, take a look at your php.ini file. Specifically, search for the "`include_path`" value. This lists every folder which is searched for files when using `include` or `require`.

For example, if your search path looks like: `include_path=".:/usr/local/lib/php"` then you could put your constants file into `/usr/local/lib/php` and just use `include 'constants.php';`.

A better idea would be to create a separate folder (e.g., /usr/local/lib/myConstants) and add this to the end of the include_path value (`include_path=".:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/myConstants"`)

Comment: sir I'm talking about include() core function like require()

Comment: @yusufiqbalpk And DaveyBox is talking about ways you could use that function.

Comment: How you include or require the file depends on your include_path value. Include will continue if the file is not found, require will halt execution. To get you working, `include ('../../includes/constants.php');` should retrieve the file but I _really_ don't recommend leaving your constants files accessible like this - one quick failure of PHP being processed (someone reboots server after removing PHP processing) and someone will be presented with the source code to the page with instructions on how to get your constants file.

Comment: PHP may access the whole filesystem, so storing the file somewhere else is just security by obscurity. Better to make sure that the file isn't readable by anything else than the web server and storing it within <?php tags without any output.

Comment: DaveyBoy is correct here I think, although maybe a teeny bit over-protective. But nyson is also half-correct (php can be configured to only access part of the filesystem) in that if the constants file is readable, it will always be readable, nomatter where you put it.

Comment: @nyson - PHP should only be able to access file which the enclosing system (e.g., Apache) or executing login (e.g, myself) has access to. I've encountered times where a file is inaccessible due to incorrect user/group rights

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [chdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) to change your working directory, although it isn't pretty and may be confusing.

Comment: Please be specific while you answer